# Can i reset the selectbox in which i have removed options with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reset, drop-down-menu

i am using the following command in a loop

```
$("#day option:last").remove();
```

and if the command is executed 2 or 3 times, my selectbox is without some of the options.

So, i need to reset the selectbox as it was in the beginning of the function.

Any help?

Comment: Might want to show the rest of your function

Answer (score 2):

You can clone the `select` element before you make any changes:

```
var copy = $('#day').clone();
```

Later, when you want to restore it, just replace the current `select` with the old one:

```
$('#day').replaceWith(copy);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the .clone() http://api.jquery.com/clone/method of jQuery, to hold a copy of your drop down list, and you can either replace the list when you want to reset the values, or you could iterate through the values in the copy and add them to the existing dropdownlist.

Here is a sample using clone in jQuery that does what I explained above.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//clone the select list
var optionlist = $("#options").clone();

//add the remove function event handler to a link
$("#remove").click(function(){

$("#options option:last").remove();

return false; //don't refresh the page

});

// add the reset click event handler to the reset link
$("#reset").click(function(){

//replace the select list with the original clone
$("#options").replaceWith(optionlist);

//clone the new list into the original optionlist variable
optionlist = $("#options").clone;

return false; //don't refresh

});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="options" multiple="true" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<a id="remove" href="#" >remove</a>
<a id="reset" href="#">reset</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question correctly in the first place.
But then a simple solution would be to use `.hide()` instead of removing the elements and cloning or keeping an additional copy.
And the reset function would do a `.show()` on the `option` elements.